# How to create expansion file having video's in raw folder?

Tags: android

I want to upload  my apk file on google play  and the size of my application apk is more than 100 mb. I have video's in raw folder and images in assests folder . I am confused in making expansion file . Please anybody help me out.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html (apk + obb)

hope this could help you.